# Branch and bound Dual Gap

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming, branch-and-bound

Let's suppose we want to solve the knapsack problem using the Branch and Bound algorithm.
I know that the algorithm ends when the optimality gap is = 0. However i have not understood how the dual bound is improved at every step.
Can you explain me ? Thanks

Comment: Can you add an easily-accessible reference to the "the knapsack problem using the Branch and Bound algorithm" that explains "gap" and "dual gap"?

Comment: dual  gap is = (upper bound -  lower bound)